# Opposition for an int

Tags: java, android, performance

i've got another question for you guys. I have a tile based game where i also have this undo function. The "push to undo" function need to invert the direction of a move(4-way).

So my directions are 0 = up, 1 = right, 2 = down, 3 = left.
And i need the easiest/most efficient way of inverting this.
This is what i came up with:

```
private void pushToUndo(int x, int y, int direction) {
    int[] args = {x,y,direction};
    int opDir = 0;

    if(direction == 0) opDir = 2;
    else if(direction == 1) opDir = 3;
    else if(direction == 2) opDir = 0;
    else if(direction == 3) opDir = 1;
    args[2] = opDir;
    undoMove = args;
    undoUsed = false;
    undoButton.setEnabled(!undoUsed);
}
```

Do anybody know of a more efficient way of getting the "opDir"(opposite direction)?

Comment: "more efficient way "? Have you benchmarked and determined you have a bottleneck here?

Comment: @MitchWheat Hi, i have not benchmarked, neither do i know if tis way is innefficient, i mostly want to know if there is a better way of doing this tan using ifs and elseifs

Comment: If you don't have a performance problem use whatever code is the easiest to understand. Period.

Comment: @MitchWheat I'm kind of new in the programming world, i love to learn new tricks and new methods as to what i can do. These kinds of questions helps me doing this

Comment: Here's new trick from an old dog: "If you don't have a performance problem use whatever code is the easiest to understand."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binary representations of the directions are

```
0: 00
1: 01
2: 10
3: 11
```

You need a way to switch between 00 <-> 10 and 01 <-> 11. This is equivalent to inverting the second bit, which is equivalent to a bitwise xor with 2.
Change your code to:

```
opDir = 2 ^ direction;
```

Computing a single bitwise operation is **very** efficient. However, you might not need to performance-tune this unless you are calling the method thousands of times per second. If you think other, slightly less efficient code is easier to understand, you can use it to increase maintainability with a negligible performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

A simple math formula will solve your problem

```
int direction;

int op = (direction + 2) % 4;
```

So the opposite direction of the `direction` will be the `op`

For example

`direction = 0` -> `op = (0 + 2) % 4 = 2;`

`direction = 1` -> `op = (1 + 2) % 4 = 3;`

`direction = 2` -> `op = (2 + 2) % 4 = 0;`

`direction = 3` -> `op = (3 + 2) % 4 = 1;`

Comment: And if anyone is concerned with performance, switch to `(direction + 2) & 3`, or better to `direction ^ 2` as McLovin writes.